# Error running IPython3 on XP: TypeError: _isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, ipython

`<UPDATE>` Never did get IPython3 to work under Windows, but I did manage to get it to work on my local CentOS server (after much frustration) by eventually discovering the absolutely indispensable [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) tool. Not sure if virtualenv would work its magic on Windows as well, but I'm content for now using IPython via SSH. `</UPDATE>`

I'm new to Python and decided to dive in with Python 3.2. I love that the language comes with a built-in interactive interpreter, but I'm looking for something more full-featured, and IPython looks like it fits the bill. I installed Distribute and used to following command from my C:\Python32\Scripts\ directory to get the egg:

```
easy_install http://archive.ipython.org/release/0.11/py3/ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg
```

This completed successfully, although the output has since gone beyond my scrollback threshold so I can't produce it here. I ran `ipython3 --help` and produced the help screen, so I know that at least part of it has installed correctly. However, when I execute `ipython3` I get the following error:

```
$ ipython3
Error in sys.excepthook:
TypeError: _isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python32\Scripts\ipython3-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==0.11', 'console_scripts', 'ipython3')()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 369, in launch_new_instance
    app.initialize()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 283, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 303, in init_shell
    ipython_dir=self.ipython_dir)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\config\configurable.py", line 295, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\frontend\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 112, in __init__
    user_global_ns=user_global_ns, custom_exceptions=custom_exceptions
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 384, in __init__
    self.db = PickleShareDB(os.path.join(self.profile_dir.location, 'db'))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\utils\pickleshare.py", line 52, in __init__
    if not self.root.isdir():
TypeError: _isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Other than `--help` I haven't yet found any other arguments that don't produce this error. I grepped for "_isdir" in C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\ and found only two references to it, in a file called tempdir.py, both shown here:

```
# XXX (ncoghlan): The following code attempts to make
# this class tolerant of the module nulling out process
# that happens during CPython interpreter shutdown
# Alas, it doesn't actually manage it. See issue #10188
_listdir = staticmethod(_os.listdir)
_path_join = staticmethod(_os.path.join)
_isdir = staticmethod(_os.path.isdir)
_remove = staticmethod(_os.remove)
_rmdir = staticmethod(_os.rmdir)
_os_error = _os.error

def _rmtree(self, path):
    # Essentially a stripped down version of shutil.rmtree.  We can't
    # use globals because they may be None'ed out at shutdown.
    for name in self._listdir(path):
        fullname = self._path_join(path, name)
        try:
            isdir = self._isdir(fullname)
```

And grepping the same directory for "isdir" returns about 100 matches; about 50% of these use 1 argument, the rest 0. I'm not sure if this is a problem with inheritance or scope or what, nor do I have any idea what the importance of the preceding underscore is. Googling "TypeError: _isdir()" returns no matches whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally decided to give this another stab, and managed to get it to work. The solution is a two-line change in the `ipython-0.11-py3.2.egg\IPython\utils\pickleshare.py` file, line 52:

Before:

```
if not self.root.isdir():
    self.root.makedirs()
```

After:

```
if not os.path.isdir(self.root):
    os.makedirs(self.root)
```